# Is it possible add OpenSSL Certificate to .pdf file?

Tags: openssl, x509certificate

I was wondering **in Windows OS** is it at all possible to add **self signed** OpenSSL Certificate to .pdf file?

If so how?
How can I verify that the certificate was successfully added to the .pdf
If not may I ask what other software may support this? 
GnuPG/GPG4Win, PGP, OpenPGP?

Comment: What is your goal?

Comment: Hi @Crypt32, This is for an assignment. It says to to **install and configure self signed certificate to the .pdf containing the master password. This should be done before encrypting .pdf with a password (in OpenSSL, PGP etc)**

Comment: Makes little sense to include the certificate there just to include. Signing certificate is automatically added to PDF during signing process. But you are talking about encryption. The assignment looks weird from what you have provided to us.